# Multiple concurrent rides for Guests not working

Tags: uber-api

When attempting multiple ride request, "request_id" of first ride is returned in the second request which means new ride is not booked for the second ride request. Please see the request/response below,

**Ride Request 1 :**

```
https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests
{
  "start_latitude": "37.713706",
  "start_longitude": "-122.403708",
  "end_latitude": "37.744186",
  "end_longitude": "-122.466388",
  "fare_id" :"48ba6200227450d3965081024657275f9d1ff5cbb719aaa0bf30be234325f300",
  "guest_id" : "5b357e78-c495-4614-afa1-e2a0b0f3dffc",
  "product_id": "a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d",
}

**Response :**

{
"status": "processing",
"product_id": "a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d",
"destination": {
"latitude": 37.744186,
"longitude": -122.466388
},
"driver": null,
"pickup": {
"latitude": 37.713706,
"longitude": -122.403708
},
"request_id": "2be01f1e-6687-4393-9fcf-e3b840803849",
"eta": null,
"location": null,
"vehicle": null,
"shared": false,
"guest": {
"guest_id": "5b357e78-c495-4614-afa1-e2a0b0f3dffc",
"phone_number": "+14150001234",
"first_name": "Jane",
"last_name": "Smith",
"email": "jane.smith@email.com"
}
}
```

**Ride Request 2 :**

```
https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests
{
  "start_latitude": "37.743033",
  "start_longitude": "-122.389675",
  "end_latitude": "37.7759073",
  "end_longitude": "-122.4245247",
  "fare_id" :"502eed0ccbb906363df23cf9e81ecb6ceb35b8af46a25194775ac9560871da12",
  "guest_id" : "ecc5adeb-fa20-4580-ac24-1ae184bffce9",
  "product_id" : "26546650-e557-4a7b-86e7-6a3942445247"
}

Response:
{
"status": "processing",
"product_id": "26546650-e557-4a7b-86e7-6a3942445247",
"destination": {
"latitude": 37.744186,
"longitude": -122.466388
},
"driver": null,
"pickup": {
"latitude": 37.713706,
"longitude": -122.403708
},
"request_id": "2be01f1e-6687-4393-9fcf-e3b840803849",
"eta": null,
"location": null,
"vehicle": null,
"shared": false,
"guest": {
"guest_id": "ecc5adeb-fa20-4580-ac24-1ae184bffce9",
"phone_number": "+14150001234",
"first_name": "Jane",
"last_name": "Smith",
"email": "jane.smith@email.com"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one concurrent ride per user/token so it is expected. In your case you just made a ride request in the sandbox and did not progress the state to completed or cancel the ride.